# How to convert System.Decimal bits to string in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, decimal

I'd like to be able to get the bits from a `System.Decimal` value and then convert that to the string representation of the value, much like `Decimal.ToString()` would do but I have a hard time coming up with the algorithm.

So I have something like this:

```
decimal d = 1403.45433M;
int[] nDecimalBits = decimal.GetBits(d);

// How to convert the 4 integers in nDecimalBits to a string
// that contains "1403.45433"?
```

I know the binary layout of the decimal - the first 3 integers contain the value bits and the last integer contains the sign bit and the scaling factor.

I tried searching for the algorithm using various search terms but decimal is mostly used as a synonym for 'floating-point number' so my searches turned up answers to unrelated problems.

Any help would be appreciated.

**Edit**: in response to some answers, I need to send the bits to a different platform where the value needs to be reconstructed. System.Decimal and any of its member functions are not available there, so I need to grab the bits and translate them to a string.

If I had a choice, I'd obviously use `ToString()` but then I wouldn't need to ask.

Comment: Why do you need to do this, why can't you use "decimal.ToString()"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you cannot use `ToString()`, you might want to check out how the mono developers implemented this:

- https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/corlib/System/NumberFormatter.cs

The entry point is [NumberToString(string, decimal, IFormatProvider)](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/corlib/System/NumberFormatter.cs#L911).

The interesting part is [InitDecHexDigits(uint, ulong)](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/corlib/System/NumberFormatter.cs#L165), which gets called like this

```
InitDecHexDigits ((uint)bits [2], ((ulong)bits [1] << 32) | (uint)bits [0]);
```

and does the "bit juggling and shifting" thing to convert the three integers into [binary coded decimals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-coded_decimal) ([`_val1` to `_val4`](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/corlib/System/NumberFormatter.cs#L124)), which can then be (trivially) converted into a string.

(Don't get confused by the fact that they call it "hex representation". It's binary coded *decimal* digits.)

Comment: Heinzi, thanks - I didn't think of this. I'll check it out, this may be exactly what I was looking for. For my purposes, BCD would be almost as good as a straight string and from BCD a string conversion is trivial, as you said. Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the Decimal constructor [Decimal(Int32[])](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t1de0ya1.aspx) to convert your value back:

> **Decimal Constructor (Int32[])**
>
> Initializes a new instance of Decimal to a decimal value represented in binary and contained in a specified array.

Afterwards, you can use `ToString` if you want.
Example:

```
decimal d = 1403.45433M;
int[] nDecimalBits = decimal.GetBits(d);

decimal d2 = new decimal(nDecimalBits);
string s = d2.ToString();
```

Comment: +1: No reason to reinvent the wheel here. Use the decimal constructor to convert the bits back into a decimal.

Comment: You haven't read my message. I don't have a weird urge to reinvent the wheel - I need to reconstruct the string value of the decimal on a platform where .NET is not available. All I have is the 4 integers that I get from the decimal from the server. I could send the text instead of the 4 ints but I need to minimize network traffic as well.

Comment: @xxbbcc: I have read your message... the information that the .NET FW is not available on the target platform is new. ;-) It might help to know *which* technology is available at the target platform. Implementing such an algorithm in Java (see my comment to Bugai13's answer) might be much easier than, for example, in C. I've added a second answer with links to mono's implementation, which works with just uint/ulong data types and some bit shifting magic.

Answer (score 4):

It's does not algoritm, but i suppose it should help.

Decimal bits [structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.getbits.aspx):

> The binary representation of a Decimal
>   number consists of a 1-bit sign, a
>   96-bit integer number, and a scaling
>   factor used to divide the integer
>   number and specify what portion of it
>   is a decimal fraction. The scaling
>   factor is implicitly the number 10,
>   raised to an exponent ranging from 0
>   to 28.
>
> The return value is a four-element
>   array of 32-bit signed integers.
>
> The first, second, and third elements
>   of the returned array contain the low,
>   middle, and high 32 bits of the 96-bit
>   integer number.
>
> The fourth element of the returned
>   array contains the scale factor and
>   sign. It consists of the following
>   parts:
>
> Bits 0 to 15, the lower word, are
>   unused and must be zero.
>
> Bits 16 to 23 must contain an exponent
>   between 0 and 28, which indicates the
>   power of 10 to divide the integer
>   number.
>
> Bits 24 to 30 are unused and must be
>   zero.
>
> Bit 31 contains the sign; 0 meaning
>   positive, and 1 meaning negative.

Comment: Thank you for your answer - I already had these details. I can do binary-to-string conversion but decimal is a more complicated case (bits in high integers need to be shifted as bits in the low integer are handled) and I couldn't figure out a solution yet.

Comment: @xxbbcc: I'm not sure why this doesn't help you... it exactly describes the format of how the Decimal is stored in the integer array. I guess the algorithm is quite straightforward: You concatenate the first three integers into some big integer data type (such as the BigInteger type of Java), then you use the 4th integer to determine where to put the decimal point. Maybe it would help if you told us where exactly you are stuck when trying to determine the algorithm.

Comment: I'm working on an extremely tight deadline and support for decimals on the target platform was thrown in at the last minute. During the conversion I have to preserve all the decimal digits, so using a double is out of question - rounding errors (outside of decimal itself) are not allowed, so I have to do a straight decimal-to-string conversion as I go through the input bits. Shifting in the right number of bits is where I got stuck - int32 is the biggest numeric type I can use during conversion.

Answer (score 2):

Is there any major reason you can't just use the decimal constructor?

```
new decimal(nDecimalBits).ToString();
```

Comment: It's true, but seems he don't like ToString, he want build decimal string from bits(extract 96 bit int value, exponent, sign).