# How to get decimal value back from the result of decimal.GetBits()

Tags: c#, .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to convert System.Decimal bits to string in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5469505/how-to-convert-system-decimal-bits-to-string-in-c)

I get int[] from decimal.GetBits(). How to get decimal value back from int[]?

Comment: solution is here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5469638/142637

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `Decimal(Int32[] bits)` constructor. Like so:

```
Decimal d = new Decimal( 123 );
Int32[] bits = d.GetBits();
Decimal e = new Decimal( bits );
Debug.Assert( d == e );
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be converted back like this:

```
var decimal = new Decimal(decimalBitArray)
```

See [MSDN Decimal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t1de0ya1.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

```
decimal dec = new decimal(decimalArray);
```